# How to animate a dashed arrow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

As the title describes, I am trying to animate a dashed arrow. I want it to look as close as possible to this on [this site](https://revolution.themepunch.com/stark-agency-website-template/).

[image]

I was able to make an arrow although I'm not sure that this was the correct way of making such arrow. I'm assuming I'd have to have drawn it with SVG...

Also the animation looks weird and I don't know how to make it smoother...

I'd appreciate some help guys :)

[This is the JsFiddle i made](https://jsfiddle.net/weinde/qkzr05uo/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=qkzr05uo)

**Here is the code:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.528571429;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body #contact {
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
body #contact .to-top-btn-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 7%;
  bottom: 15%;
}
body #contact .to-top-btn-wrapper .btn-text-wrapper {
  margin: -35px auto;
}
body #contact .to-top-btn-wrapper .btn-text-wrapper .btn-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #676565;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
body #contact .to-top-btn-wrapper .to-top-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 35px;
  bottom: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
body #contact .to-top-btn-wrapper .to-top-btn .line {
  border-right: 0.1rem dashed #676565;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: show 1000ms linear forwards infinite;
}
body #contact .to-top-btn-wrapper .to-top-btn .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.3rem;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1rem;
  border-right: 0.1rem solid #676565;
  display: inline-block;
}
body #contact .to-top-btn-wrapper .to-top-btn .right {
  left: 0.3rem;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
body #contact .to-top-btn-wrapper .to-top-btn .left {
  right: 0.3rem;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
@keyframes show {
  0% {
    height: 5rem;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="to-top-btn-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-text-wrapper">
      <span class="btn-text">Scroll to top</span>
    </div>
    <div class="to-top-btn">
      <span class="arrow left"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="arrow right"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Inspecting the code on the page you provided, gives the answer. Why not follow what they did? It's nothing fancy. They use keyframes to anime 'transform' with value of `matrix3d`

Comment: OK, not just `matrix3d`. Look at each element in the container. There's quite a few tricks they use. But most is done using animations. You can use keyframes. Seems like they're using JS since it's in the element style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `clip-path` animation with some background can do it

```css
.arrow {
  width: 20px;
  margin:10px;
  height: 150px; 
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom:4px;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(currentColor 50%, transparent 50%) top/2px 15px content-box repeat-y;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
  animation:hide infinite 2s linear;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 80%;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 1px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    clip-path:polygon(0 100%,100% 100%,100% 100%,0 100%);
  }
  50.1% {
    clip-path:polygon(0 0   ,100% 0   ,100% 0   ,0 0);
  }
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>

<div class="arrow" style="transform:scaleY(-1)"></div>
```

A similar idea using `mask`

```css
.arrow {
  width: 20px;
  margin:10px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-bottom:4px;
  display:inline-block;  
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(currentColor 50%, transparent 50%) top/2px 15px content-box repeat-y;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-size:100% 0%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  mask-size:100% 0%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:hide infinite 2s linear;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 80%;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 1px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
     -webkit-mask-size:100% 100%; 
     -webkit-mask-position:top;  
     mask-size:100% 100%; 
     mask-position:top;      
  }
  50.1% {
     -webkit-mask-size:100% 100%; 
     -webkit-mask-position:bottom;
     mask-size:100% 100%; 
     mask-position:bottom;   
  }
  100% {
     -webkit-mask-position:bottom;
     mask-position:bottom;  
  }
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>

<div class="arrow" style="transform:scaleY(-1)"></div>
```

---

Here is a background only solution with no clip-path:

```css
.arrow {
  width: 20px;
  margin:10px;
  height: 150px; 
  display:inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom left, 
     transparent    calc(50% - 1px), 
     currentColor 0 calc(50% + 1px),
     transparent  0) 
   bottom left/10px 10px,
    
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, 
     transparent    calc(50% - 1px), 
     currentColor 0 calc(50% + 1px),
     transparent  0) 
   bottom right/10px 10px,
    
   repeating-linear-gradient(currentColor 0 7px, transparent 7px 15px) 
   bottom/2px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-clip:content-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:hide infinite 2s linear;
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    padding:150px 0 0;
  }
  50.1% {
    padding:0 0 150px;
  }
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>

<div class="arrow" style="transform:scaleY(-1)"></div>
```

Another version with less gradient:

```css
.arrow {
  width: 20px;
  margin:10px;
  height: 150px; 
  display:inline-flex;
}
.arrow:before,
.arrow:after{
  content:"";
  width:50%;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom left, 
     transparent    calc(50% - 1px), 
     white        0 calc(50% + 1px),
     transparent  0) 
   bottom/100% 10px,
    
   repeating-linear-gradient(white 0 7px, transparent 0 15px) 
   right/1px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-clip:content-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:hide infinite 2s linear;
}
.arrow:after {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}
@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    padding:150px 0 0;
  }
  50.1% {
    padding:0 0 150px;
  }
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>

<div class="arrow" style="transform:scaleY(-1)"></div>
```

And with CSS variables to easily control everything:

```css
.arrow {
  --h:150px;   /* height */
  --w:20px;    /* width */
  --b:7px;     /* width of the dash*/
  --g:8px;     /* gap between dashes*/
  width: var(--w);
  margin:10px;
  height: var(--h); 
  display:inline-flex;
}
.arrow:before,
.arrow:after{
  content:"";
  width:50%;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom left, 
     transparent    calc(50% - 1px), 
     white        0 calc(50% + 1px),
     transparent  0) 
   bottom/100% calc(var(--w)/2),
    
   repeating-linear-gradient(white 0 var(--b), transparent 0 calc(var(--b) + var(--g))) 
   right/1px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-clip:content-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation:hide infinite 2s linear;
}
.arrow:after {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}
@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    padding:var(--h) 0 0;
  }
  50.1% {
    padding:0 0 var(--h);
  }
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="arrow" style="transform:scaleY(-1);--h:100px;--g:3px;"></div>
<div class="arrow" style="--h:120px;--b:3px;--w:30px"></div>
<div class="arrow" style="transform:scaleY(-1);--h:150px;--b:5px;--g:10px;--w:40px"></div>
```

Comment: Bro thanks a lot :D have a virtual internet beer on me! :D

Comment: @weinde added another idea in case you want better support than clip-path

Comment: bro nice work! tbh I wasnt expecting anything like this :D U kinda restored my faith in this place

Answer (score 3):

toke a different approach to the arrow animation.

you can use SVG instead of text.

POC:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.arrow-container {
  padding: 0 50px;
  animation: scrolling 2s infinite linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
}

.arrow {
  animation: scrolling-a 2s infinite linear;
}

.arrow-point {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 -50px -10px;
}

@keyframes scrolling {
  0% {
    margin-top: 150px;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 150px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scrolling-a {
  0% {
    margin-top: -150px;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
  <div class="arrow">
    <span class="arrow-point">^</span><br> |
    <br> |
    <br> |
    <br> |
    <br> |
    <br> |
    <br> |
  </div>
</div>
```